# Importing Windows-Ansi DBF to SQL Server loses some character data

Tags: sql-server-2008, encoding, collation, dbf

I have a DBF file that is encoded as Windows-ANSI (Windows Code Page 1252). I am using an ODBC driver to import this file as a table into a SQL Server database. When I do I lose some character information.

First, to verify the DBF file was encoded as expected I opened up the file with a hex editor and searched for the character in question. It's a "small-bullet" on code page 1252, and it was stored at 0x95 in the file so, for at least  that character, the encoding seems to be as expected.

I did a search and found someone saying that importing to a nvarchar as opposed to a varchar column would make a difference, so when I did the import I re-mapped the column containing the problematic character to nvarchar.

The database it is imported into has a collation of "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and from a page I read on MSDN the "CP1" indicates this should be equivalent to windows code page 1252.

When I do the import the character is being imported as 0xf2 or 0x5625. I haven't found any reason as to why the different imports to this point.

Has anyone come across an issue such as this? What did you do to resolve it? Anything I should be looking into or trying that I haven't as of yet?

Comment: I did some more digging into this and I discovered that the 0xB7 values were being translated into 0x5625. I connected the ODBC driver to different sources (excel and a VB app) and got the same issue in those so I'm assuming this is a ODBC thing. Also of note is that for the values 0x5625, 2+5=7 and 5+6=B.

Comment: One more comment on this. The 0x5625 value for B7 could just be coincidence. This only happens when I import the data into a nvarchar in SQL server. Any other access of the ODBC connection produces 0x2B. I went through all the values from 0 to 255 and it seems that ODBC is incorrectly reporting the values for everything 0x80 and higher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be an issue with an old driver. Upgrading to a newer DBF driver fixed the character issue but presented another issue. The new drivers lack any "ordinal" information in the column schema, so it can't be used with the DTS Wizard, or at least I couldn't find a way to do so.

Installing the Microsoft Visual FoxPro OLEDB drivers worked flawlessly. Once they're installed, they show up as a data source in the DTS Wizard, and can be used to import directly. This fixed my character issue and I was able to do my import.